# MYSQL GROUP BY query in db with 100 000 000+ rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to get 20 last chats with one last message grouped by renter order by id DESC
Then, next 20 chats and next...
Еhere are 100 000 000+ rows in DB and the request takes a very long time to complete

Request examples:

```
SELECT renter, MAX(id) FROM support 
GROUP BY renter
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Then second request (#1235 - This version of MySQL does not yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery')

```
SELECT * FROM support_message WHERE support IN (...)
```

And the next request:

1. (15.37s) :

   SELECT id, renter FROM support
   WHERE renter NOT IN(..., ...)
   GROUP BY (renter)
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
2. (> 2 min) :

   SELECT id, renter FROM support
   WHERE id < ...
   GROUP BY (renter)
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20

JOIN request has been running for more than 5 minutes:

```
SELECT * FROM support_message
JOIN support ON support.id = support_message.support
GROUP BY (renter) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

[image: db scheme]

How can this problem be solved?
There is still time to make changes in the database structure.

Comment: The first query is malformed. If you are grouping by `renter`, then there can be multple `id` values per group. Which one do you want? any of them, the max, the min, the average?

Comment: MySQL is an OLTP database. If you're trying to do reports over 100M rows, you should use a data warehouse, e.g. [ClickHouse](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse), [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/), [Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/), or others. I don't think MySQL will ever run this type of query at the scale you describe with satisfactory performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler I need last record (max id or max datetime)

Comment: @BillKarwin I can use only MYSQL in this project